# why do we need to do typecasting in this particular line

Tags: java, jsp

can anyone please explain me why do we need to typecast in the given line

```
mypack.adder rect=(mypack.adder) session.getAttribute("rect");
```

what does session.getAttribute  is actually doing? and what does session.setAttribute(string,object) does?
how does string relates to the object?

Comment: you always have the docs to see the return type of a method, and to understand what that method does.

Comment: Because `session.getAttribute(...)` returns `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Every class in java extends the java.lang.Object class. This is useful for many cases such as this. The session holds attributes, but it doesn't limit you to the type of the attribute - it holds the attributes as Object type objects. Since java is statically typed (the compiler needs to know the type of every variable) you need to explicitly cast the attribute you have just get from the session to your type, as getAttribute() returns java.lang.Object object. See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting